# reading out multi dimensional array

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

the multi array is read in correctly
but reading out the array he messes up.
the action that suppose to be done on each element from array in array, he doesn't do it anymore when more indexes in 2 array are made.

when a second index in 2 array i made he doesn't do this action anymore on previous index, only the last made index.

thanks

```
private var Enemy:Array = new Array();//1st array
private var EnemyHull:Array = new Array(); 
private var waves:Array = new Array();//2 array ==> array 1 get in this

private function enterFrame(e:Event):void
    {                               
        //Enemy Ai
        for(var i2:uint; i2 < waves.length; i2++){
            for(var i:uint; i < Enemy.length; i++){
                waves[i2][i].x -= 1;//when a second index in 2 array i made he doesn't do this action anymore on previous index, only the last made index.
            }
        }
    }

private function enemySpawnen(event:TimerEvent):void
    {           
        for(var i:uint = 0; i < hoeveelheidEnemy;i++){
            //
            }

            if(Enemy[i] != null){;
                viewContainer.addChild(Enemy[i]);
                //
            }
        }
        waves[iwaves] = Enemy;
        iwaves++;
    }

 function shoot(e:Event):void
            {
                //                  
                try{
                    for(var i2:uint; i2 < waves.length; i2++){
                        for(var i:uint = Enemy.length-1; i >= 0;i--){
                            if(kogel.hitTestObject(waves[i2][i])){
                                //
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                    catch(e:Error){

                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your for loops misses an important thing to work properly : you have to initialize your iterator (i or i2) to a starting value.

You wrote :

```
for(var i2:uint; i2 < waves.length; i2++){
        for(var i:uint; i < Enemy.length; i++){
            waves[i2][i].x -= 1;
        }
    }
```

But what you need is :

```
for(var i2:uint = 0; i2 < waves.length; i2++){
        for(var i:uint = 0; i < Enemy.length; i++){
            waves[i2][i].x -= 1;
        }
    }
```

Dont forget the **= 0** in your loop declaration !